# Stripe API being recursive on its own

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

I am calling various stripe APIs using this function I created:

```
    function api_stripe($api_type,$vars_array,$test_live)
    {

            if($api_type == 'createToken') $url_endpoint = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens';
            else if($api_type == 'createCharge') $url_endpoint = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges';
            else if($api_type == 'updateCharge') 
            {
                $url_endpoint = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges/'.$vars_array['charge_id'];
                unset($vars_array['charge_id']);
            }
            else if($api_type == 'captureCharge') 
            {
                $url_endpoint = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges/'.$vars_array['charge_id'].'/capture';
                unset($vars_array['charge_id']);
            }
            else if($api_type == 'refundCharge') 
            {
                $url_endpoint = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/refunds';
            }
            else if($api_type == 'createCustomer')
            {
                $url_endpoint = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers';
            }

            if($test_live == 'test') $apiKey = 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //test
            else if($test_live == 'live') $apiKey = 'sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //live

            $post_data = http_build_query($vars_array);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$apiKey));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $response;

    }
```

It works fine unless I call from a file called "functions.php" - then it goes ape-shit and stripe starts sending 1000s of webhooks.  Although it only returns 1 response to the page I requested it from (i.e. https://www.example.com/functions.php).

Is there a reason it would do this from a file called "functions.php" (when it doesn't do it from test.php or even functions2.php).  Did I identify a bug or is this something known.

Here is the code I ran on my function:

```
    $vars_array = array(
            "email" => "abcdefgxyz@gmail.com",
            "source" => array(
                        "name" => "testFirst2 testLast2",
                        "number" => "4242424242424242",
                        "exp_month" => "12",
                        "exp_year" => "2017",
                        "cvc" => "123",
                        "object" => "card"
                        )               
            );

    $createCustomer = api_stripe('createCustomer',$vars_array,'test');
    echo $createCustomer;
```

I don't dare try it live yet.  Stripe support said the code was fine:

> Based on the timing of these "create customer" calls, 3 separate requests were sent to Stripe from your code.

However when I looked at their 3 examples, it was the exact same timestamp - when I only accessed the function once.

I don't see the function calling itself.  I create the $vars_array outside of the function and then pass them into the function when I call it.  But again it works from any file other than a file titled "functions.php". Weird.

Can anyone corroborate this?  And is my code doing something that would make the api_stripe function recursive?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Stripe PHP SDK?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with this code.  I suspect the issue lay elsewhere inside of your two files.

Comment: 1 file, testing it by calling it from the browser.

Comment: Friend brought up the fact that "functions" may be a key word of sorts screwing up the API receiving URL endpoint.  I have moved on and have stuck the function in another named file and everything is working fine.